Difference between a normal if-case pattern and a if-case pattern with null-check subpattern
I'm having trouble understanding how the null-check works differently from a normal if-case statement, and when and why I would use it over a normal one.
The doc mentions one of the benefits of using this feature is to "match failures without throwing."
Here is my short example code:
void test(String? fetchedData) {
  if (fetchedData case final String name) {
    log("My name is : $name");
  }
  if (fetchedData case final String name?) {
    log("My name is : $name");
  }
  return;
}

If you use this code with VSCode and hover on the $name variable, you will see that both are suggested by VSCode to be type promoted to a non-nullable String type, and can be use securely.
If my understanding is correct, if I pass null or a type incompatible with String, the if block won't be executed, as the pattern matching will fail, and no error will be thrown.

It's your String type.  If it was a nullable type, that would require the value to be non-null.  However the nullcheck here is in fact redundant.

in case final String name? name is already declared as a non-nullable type so the null check pattern won't have an effect. If you were to instead do case final name? or even case final String? name? then the null check pattern would have an effect.

The example you cited doc is slightly different from your example, in that the pattern case var s? does not contain a fixed type.
To showcase the usefullness of a null check pattern, your example could be amended:
void test(Object? fetchedData) {
  print(fetchedData.runtimeType);

  if (fetchedData case final nonNullData?) {
    print("  fetchedData: $nonNullData");
  }
}

and
void main() {
  String? a;
  final String b = 'Ben';
  final c = 27;

  test(a);
  test(b);
  test(c);
}

The console output is listed below:
Null
String
  fetchedData: Ben
int
  fetchedData: 27


The statement from the docs:

To treat null values as match failures without throwing, use the null-check pattern.

could indeed be formulated a bit clearer. My understanding is that treating null values as a match failure ensures that the object is not inadvertently accessed in a non-null context, which may then lead to an error being thrown.

So I guess one situation where I could use this is when I don't know the shape of the input and need to separate handling for when it is null and when it is something concrete ?

I use it a lot in final v? which matches any non-null value promoting it to the corresponding non-nullable type
